# Vue/Nuxt Routing issue: Why does "wrong" component load during a specific route?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

Can someone tell me why the following component is loaded when I refresh the browser?

Sandbox link: **https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-darkness-vwklt?file=/pages/index.vue**

Let me explain.

**What I want to happen and my expected output:**

1.) Click "doss" --> Profile and Settings --> [The Profile Page with data is shown]

2.) Then, REFRESH/RELOAD the browser, the profile page is STILL shown with the same data

3.) The URL did not change.

**What actually happens and the unexpected output:**

1a.) Click "doss" --> Profile and Settings --> [The Profile Page with data is shown]

2a.) Then, REFRESH/RELOAD the browser, *the profile page is NOT shown but instead another component is loaded with the title "The Post Detail Page" .*

3a.) The URL did not change.

***Why does #2a happen? The URL has not changed but the component did.***

What am I doing wrong? Here is my NuxtJS folder structure:

[image]

Comment: You can't have two child route with dynamic route parameter. How do you expect the vue-router to choose which one to use? Check your `.nuxt/routes.json` file

Comment: Unfortunately, did not make a difference. Updated pages like so: https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-darkness-vwklt?file=/pages/_displayName/post/index.vue

Answer (score 1):

To add a **dynamic route in Nuxt**, create a file starting with a dash. You already did that, which is totally fine, like;

*_myPage.vue* or add a folder named *_myPage* containg a *index.vue* file inside.

But your example won't work because nuxt is missing the "doss" route from your link / menu item.
Working example;
https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-voice-6pofd?file=/pages/doss/_displayName/index.vue

[image: index.vue inside a _displayName folder]

URL path will result in `/doss/xxx`

Also see; [Nuxt dynamic pages](https://nuxtjs.org/examples/routing/dynamic-pages/)